# Bootstrap Carousel on mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site which uses the bootstrap carousel. On the desktop the carousel works fine. 
On my smartphone the carousel is wider than the screen. This means I can scroll to the right.

I was looking where this come from and I think it is because of the overlay for the next button. This dark field with lowered opacity can be seen on the right of the site. This only happens on my smartphone. Disabling the background of this container didn't help.

You can look at the site at http://christophkreibich.de/sandbox/0017

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are you formatting your HTML with the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your site isn't working correctly on desktop either (still has a scroll). Your problem is you don't have a container. You have to put the `row` in a container. Look at your markup.

Should be like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">Content here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That said, the carousel isn't supposed to reside in a container at all. See [example here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/). The captions are inside a container (in each carousel item).

You need to update the markup on the entire site.

Without a container and its positive padding, the negative margins created by the row will create the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Okey this worked for the carousel. Thank you :) ... Now my navbar is to wide. I tried to set the padding to 0 etc., but nothing seems to work.

Comment: The navbar is fine. It's all the code below the carousel. The navbar has a nested container to house the contents. You have rows without containers below your carousel. They ALL need to be in a container (everything below the Showreel comment).